# COALESCE is returning a text type instead of a time_stamp type in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to use COALESCE to deal with sql injections in Go.

```
query := `SELECT mc.company_name_full, msc.company_id, msc.cdate, %s
          FROM %s AS mc INNER JOIN %s AS msc
          ON (mc.id = msc.company_id)
          WHERE %s AND
          msc.company_id = COALESCE($1, msc.company_id) AND
          mc.company_name_full ~* COALESCE($2, mc.company_name_full) AND
          msc.cdate >= '2017-07-01' AND
          msc.cdate <= '%s'`
query = fmt.Sprintf(query, selectParam, companyTable, statsTable, whereParam, time.Now().Local().Format("2006-01-02"))
```

This query works, but when I try to use COALESCE with Time_stamp

```
query := `SELECT mc.company_name_full, msc.company_id, msc.cdate, %s
          FROM %s AS mc INNER JOIN %s AS msc
          ON (mc.id = msc.company_id)
          WHERE %s AND
          msc.company_id = COALESCE($1, msc.company_id) AND
          mc.company_name_full ~* COALESCE($2, mc.company_name_full) AND
          msc.cdate >= COALESCE($3, '2017-07-01') AND
          msc.cdate <= COALESCE($4, '%s')`
```

but I get this error

```
pq:operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= text
```

What can I do to ensure that COALESCE returns a timestamp type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **cast** the `text` string to a `timestamp`, like so:

```
`SELECT mc.company_name_full, msc.company_id, msc.cdate, %s
      FROM %s AS mc INNER JOIN %s AS msc
      ON (mc.id = msc.company_id)
      WHERE %s AND
      msc.company_id = COALESCE($1, msc.company_id) AND
      mc.company_name_full ~* COALESCE($2, mc.company_name_full) AND
      msc.cdate >= COALESCE($3, '2017-07-01'::timestamp) AND
      msc.cdate <= COALESCE($4, '%s'::timestamp)`
```

**General Caveat:**

I'm not too familiar with the syntax of *Go*, but from what I can tell, `%s` here is used by `Sprintf` for direct formatting (interpolation), so having these in your `where` clause still technically allows *SQL Injection*.

Anywhere possible (and for some things, like table names, it really isn't, but even in that case you need to be as careful as possible from where the variables that are interpolated come), *bindings* should be used.

e.g. why can't `time.Now().Local().Format("2006-01-02")` be passed as a binding and not interpolated?

**Update in response to comment from OP:**

From the [Go lib/pq package doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq), in the example code:

```
rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT name FROM users WHERE favorite_fruit = $1
    OR age BETWEEN $2 AND $2 + 3`, "orange", 64)
```

the `$1` and `$2` are *bindings*. That is to say, the library handles escaping them (*Go*'s `pq` package is a *Go* wrapper around the pure *Postgres libpq* library), and should prevent *SQL Injection*. They *bind* (that is, connect to) the arguments that are subsequently passed.

e.g. `$1` maps to `"orange"` and `$2` maps to `64`.

The references to `%s` in your original queries, in contrast, are directly formatted -- meaning there is no *Postgres*-based (*libpq*) escaping, and as such, no protection from *SQL Injection*. The values are simply passed right on through.

More detail on [*Go formatting*](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

Comment: I'm not too familar with the term interpole and binding, would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @richard_d_sim: Added to my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @khampson's answer, CAST(expression as type) can convert types.

Also agree on the risk of sql injection; coalesce by itself is not an effective way to prevent it.

Use prepared queries & bind parameters for general parameter substitution. To substitute table name variables, go sql package doesn't yet provide a standard interface ([in progress](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18478)), so use a database library specific quote function, eg: [QuoteIdentifier](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#QuoteIdentifier). See also [postgres parameter quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE) examples.